# How to append numbers for contact number?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

The result I wanted to achieve was something like this.

Contact Number:
[(+639) -- --- ---- ]<< this is a text box (the '-' are spaces)

the (+639) in the text box is already there. Its not just a placeholder.
For example, I input numbers in the text box on it like : [(+639) 32 456 7853],

the (+639) would be saved to the database and not just '32 456 7853'...

How do can I achieve this kind of output?

Comment: so just this `<input .. value="(+639)" maxlength="15" size="15">`..

Comment: so you want to enforce that specific format, including the spaces? I so, a function call on change could handle that, but if it's not that important, you could do smith's suggestion--Even if you need that format in your database, you can do that after the user hits submit.

Comment: if im filling one in i would prefer to see `<span>(+639)</span> <input .. value="" maxlength="15" size="15">` .. then you can just as the string "(+639)" back when adding to db. https://jsfiddle.net/b2mnfc9y/1/

Comment: Is `+639` fixed for any input?

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are looking for `input masking`:

There are multiple libraries which can do this:

https://unmanner.github.io/imaskjs/

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-input-mask-phone-number

or something like this

https://www.jquery-az.com/4-demos-of-input-masking-solution-by-using-javascript/

Comment: link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: The answer is not 'link only'; I specified the solution for his problem which is `input masking` and I give him some alternatives... what would you expect more?

Comment: all you have is links, its clearly a link only answer, not one ounce of code